# As Office365 Admin, is it possible to view results of user's Microsoft Forms?

Tags: microsoft-forms

One of my users created a Microsoft Forms survey and went on leave. I'm an Office365 admin. I know it's possible for me to change their password and log in as them, and see the results of the form, but I'd prefer to do it without interrupting them. Do I have the ability as an admin to see the results of a Microsoft Forms survey?

EDIT : There is the ability to transfer ownership, intended for people who's accounts have been closed.  Not what's needed today, but may be useful later : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-forms/admin-information